# How to repair shower faucet/valve leak and identifying replacement parts

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet, plumbing-fixture

My shower faucet is leaking. Please see my photo here.

[image: picture of leaky shower faucet]
[image: cover of the instruction manual for pressure-balanced ProFlo Tub & Shower Faucet]

I think it is a "Ferguson" brand "pressure-balanced" shower faucet; I think the model is "ProFlo" (aka "Pro Flo")?

- What kind of replacement "cartridge" I might need?
- What is the cartridge part number?
- Do I need to cut out the wall in front, or behind the shower, to access the plumbing?
- How can I go about the fix?

This question is similar, I will follow the instructions here:

- [how to replace leaking tub/shower faucet stem](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/161545/126311)

These videos are helpful (when I Google "how to repair shower faucet").

Most videos suggest I can just remove the front-plate/escutcheon, "replace a cartridge", and then I'm done.

- But what cartridge do I buy?
- And are there any videos showing how to replace this specific model of shower valve/faucet/cartridge?
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMEVFDfiSiw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kz3Td5QKHFA

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cartridges vary greatly, even between the same models. Turn off the water to your house and open a hot and cold faucet to release the pressure. Then get an adjustable wrench and turn that big brass nut counterclockwise and remove it. Slowly pull the cartridge out noting the position of any marking to assist you in installing the new one. Go to your home store or plumbing supply store and get an exact replacement cartridge. Install it and you're good to go. If you check behind the chrome trim, there might be some shutoff valves to the shower that you can use instead of turning off the water to the entire house.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Giving you the right answer because I assume if I follow your advice (take in cartridge to find replacement) I'll solve my problem, and because you implied an answer to other questions i.e. I should *not* need to cut out a wall.

Comment: @TheRedPea the only reason you would need to open the wall up is if you discover the leak is in the pipes, not in the faucet itself.